# Using Scrapy，how can I jump back to the point where Request's errback function was called?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

When an exception was raised while processing the request, the *errback*  function will be called. The question is, how can I jump back to the point where  the *errback* function was called?
For example:

```
for url in self.urls:
    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_httpbin,
                        errback=self.errback_httpbin,
                        dont_filter=True)

def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
    #do something to fix the error#
```

If when processing url[k], *errback_httpbin* is called, how can I **jump back to process url[k] in the for loop**.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can give an advice :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [official guide](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html):

> errback (callable) – a function that will be called if any exception was raised while processing the request. This includes pages that failed with 404 HTTP errors and such. It receives a Twisted Failure instance as first parameter.

The [Twisted Failure](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.python.failure.Failure.html) object contains some useful methods and properties that might help you:

> Instance Variable  value:  the exception instance responsible for this failure.
>
> Instance Variable  type:   the exception's class.
>
> Instance Variable  stack:  list of frames, innermost last, excluding Failure. __ init __.
>
> Instance Variable  frames: list of frames, innermost first.
>
> Method getTracebackObject: get an object that represents this Failure's stack that can be passed to traceback.extract_tb.
>
> Method getErrorMessage:    get a string of the exception which caused this Failure.

Or you can try with debugging. My favorite method is to add a main.py that you can launch from the IDE in debug mode, letting you using breakpoints etc... the content of main.py will be:

```
from scrapy import cmdline
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl yourspider".split())
```